# angular js Services.. Access to restricted URI denied

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Access to restricted URI denied. iam using http service...

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,
$http) 
{
  $http.get("predefineService.htm.htm").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
  });
});
```

Comment: are you running the HTML file locally? For example : C:/Users/Me/Desktop/MyProject/index.html?

Comment: Why is it predefineService.htm.htm shouldnt it be only 1x htm? or is this just a mistake in the example?